# nhibernate hydration performance

Tags: performance, nhibernate

**Context:**
Domain model of *Documents* having *Editions* and *Tags*.

What kind of figures are you going to expect when hydrating using nHibernate?

My domain model not very complex and when I query all Documents fetching Editions as well as Tags the query returns a little more than 8000 rows from the database - which in turn are hydrated into about 2300 Documents.

The database operation takes about 100ms and the hydration process takes 4000ms, which I find very strange.

dotTrace indicates a large number of calls (1.6M) to

> "System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.ColumnName(SQLiteStatement, Int32)"

and the like.

The query is performed using Criteria like this:

```
var docsQuery = _session.CreateCriteria<Document>();            
docsQuery.SetFetchMode("Editions", FetchMode.Join);
docsQuery.SetFetchMode("Tags", FetchMode.Join);
docsQuery.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
return docsQuery .List<Document>();
```

**Note:** Surely limiting the resultset will improve the performance. My primary concern was on why the bad hydration performance in general. Fiddling with session.FlushMode and session.CacheMode does not help a lot in my case.

**UPDATE:** Here is a screenshot from the profiler.

[image: dotTrace]

**UPDATE 2:** Checked the query times and they are about 100ms in all.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of your dotTrace profiling?

Comment: Updated with a screenshot. Note that the same both SQL Server and SQLite performed the same.

Comment: @JensJ, I find it hard to believe that the DB call takes 1ms to return 8000 rows.

Comment: @Diego it could, if its in-memory as SQLite is

Comment: @Jaguar It's still too little. I'm more inclined to believe that what takes 1ms is the call to ExecuteReader (which does *not* fetch all the results)

Comment: Actually it runs on an SSD so the performance is pretty amazing. Even if NHprof's measures on db-time are wrong I have verified that the query takes a few _milli_seconds and not _seconds_. Focus of my question is on the hydration process, not really the query this time.

Comment: What's the stack trace for the `ColumnName` calls?

Comment: Why aren't you paging your results? Returning 8k rows of something is alot.

Comment: Sure paging will help, but the main question was really about the hydration process/performance in general. I was really confused to see that some calls were made a million times when the actual number of entities were about 2000.

Comment: @Jensj Can you provide any mapping details ? Seems like something is going wrong ...

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I came to this question searching for exactly the same. On total in-database query times of 35ms I'm seeing around 400ms by the time it's hydrated.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try a query without using `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer`? (You may need to solve the N+1 problem, but there are solutions for that.)
- Have you turned on the reflection optimizer?